# In Azure DocumentDb, how do I write an "IN" statement using LINQ to SQL

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to retrieve about 50 - 100 documents by their ID from DocumentDb. I have the list of IDs in a `List<string>`. How do I use LINQ to SQL to retrieve those documents. I don't want to write the actual SQL query as a string, as in:

```cs
IQueryable<Family> results = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionUri, "SELECT * FROM family WHERE State IN ('TX', 'NY')", DefaultOptions);
```

I want to be able to use lambda expressions to create the query, because I don't want to hard-code the names of the fields as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you do not want to generate and pass query string `SELECT * FROM family WHERE State IN ('TX', 'NY')` to query documents, you could try the following code.

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>() { "TX", "NY" };

client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionUri).Where(d => ids.Contains(d.id));
```

Comment: Any updates? Does the reply help you solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This gives me the right result. But the **Note** seems to be inaccurate. This actually does server-side filtering, NOT in-memory (client side) filtering. The generated SQL query has the IN statement and is executed on the server. The `client.CreateDocumentQuery` returns a `IQueryable` and not an `IEnumerable`(in-memory).

Comment: I checked it again, it indeed passes the query to server.